# In Spring, when transactions happen close to each other, can they get merged?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions

### Context

I support a fairly conventional Spring Boot application, which uses a transactional datastore (Oracle). The data source is configured as an instance of `HikariDataSource`, and setting up of the transaction manager is left to Spring Boot.

Service methods are annotated with plain `@Transactional` annotation, which implies `Propagation.REQUIRED`. There are no `@Transactional` annotations at lower levels (i.e., Dao).

### Symptoms

The symptoms I am observing now are:

- Through a duplicated request, the `@Transactional` method is being called twice in quick succession, with the same arguments.

  - First invocation is successful.
  - Second invocation fails due to duplication, and rolls back its transaction.
- The end result within the database is as if none of the invocations occurred.

My suspicion is that the two invocations manage to somehow share a physical transaction.

### Questions

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#tx-propagation) states that:

> `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` enforces a physical transaction, either locally for the current scope if no transaction exists yet or participating in an existing 'outer' transaction defined for a larger scope.

So far I was not able to get a clear understanding of what the "'outer' transaction" means.

My questions are:

- Is the term "'outer' transaction" restricted to one `@Transactional` method calling another `@Transactional` method?
- Given the `Propagation.REQUIRED` setting, when a non-nested `@Transactional` method is called twice in a quick succession, is it possible that both invocations will share the same physical transaction?

Comment: It would be better to create a sample project demonstrating this problem

Comment: @sify So far I was not able to replicate this problem, unfortunately, and only found a single occurrence in production logs.